# Why count() and ROW_NUMBER() OVER are not properly working in Hibernate's native query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

First of all, here are the technologies used: hibernate v5.1.0.Final, javaee-api 7.0, Java 8, Postgres 9.6.1
Given is the **postgres** db:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar NOT NULL ,
  last_name varchar NOT NULL ,
  hired_date date
);
CREATE TABLE ticket (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_ticket_id bigint REFERENCES ticket (id),
  code varchar,
  description varchar
);
CREATE TYPE ticket_status AS ENUM ('OPENED', 'RESOLVED', 'CLOSED');
CREATE TABLE tickets_assigned (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  employee_id bigint REFERENCES employee (id) NOT NULL ,
  ticket_id bigint REFERENCES ticket (id) NOT NULL ,
  status ticket_status,
  assigned_date timestamp,
  resolved_date timestamp,
  closed_date timestamp,
  UNIQUE (employee_id, ticket_id)
);
```

I insert some values into the DB. E.g. i insert Elvis Presley with all the stuff 
having 1 ticket closed.
Then I create a query in psql(take into account the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER, COUNT and GROUP BY`) to look at Elvis's statistics:

```
SELECT e.id,
       e.name,
       e.last_name,
       e.hired_date,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY e.id ASC),
       COUNT(a.id)
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN assigned_tickets a ON e.id=a.employee_id
AND a.status='CLOSED'
GROUP BY e.id
```

This works superbly for me, returning smth like:

```
...
2 elvis presley 1967-10-10 2 1
...
```

Then I use the

```
Entitymanager.createNativeQuery(...)
```

in my EJB project with Hibernate v5.1.0 for the SAME SQL QUERY, and that's what i get:

1. `COUNT()` with `GROUP BY` return 0 in any case, disregarding the input.
2. Hibernate laments on `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(e.id ASC)`, making me to write this expression like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()`, that results in behavior i have not expected (like `2 guys with #3` and `1 guy with #2` in `list.length=3`).

Elvis becomes like:    `2 elvis presley 1967-10-10 3 0`

How can i fix these two problems?
I kindly ask for your help. Can provide all the other stuff if needed.

**UPD.**

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT e.id as ID, e.name AS NAME," +
            " e.last_name AS LAST_NAME, e.hired_date AS HIRED_DATE," +
            "  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY e.id ASC) AS ROW_NUM, COUNT(a.id) AS NUM_CLOSED  FROM employee e" +
            " LEFT JOIN assigned_tickets a ON e.id=a.employee_id AND a.status='CLOSED' GROUP BY e.id",
            "EmpDtoMapping")
            .getResultList()
```

> Hibernate laments: 
>   `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: ?????????????? ?????? ? ????????? SQL "SELECT E.ID AS ID, E.NAME AS NAME, E.LAST_NAME AS LAST_NAME, E.HIRED_DATE AS HIRED_DATE,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER[*] BY E.ID ASC) AS ROW_NUM, COUNT(A.ID) AS NUM_CLOSED FROM EMPLOYEE E LEFT JOIN ASSIGNED_TICKETS A ON E.ID=A.EMPLOYEE_ID AND A.STATUS='CLOSED' GROUP BY E.ID "; ????????? ")"
>   Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT E.ID AS ID, E.NAME AS NAME, E.LAST_NAME AS LAST_NAME, E.HIRED_DATE AS HIRED_DATE,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER[*] BY E.ID ASC) AS ROW_NUM, COUNT(A.ID) AS NUM_CLOSED FROM EMPLOYEE E LEFT JOIN ASSIGNED_TICKETS A ON E.ID=A.EMPLOYEE_ID AND A.STATUS='CLOSED' GROUP BY E.ID "; expected ")"; SQL statement:
>   SELECT e.id as ID, e.name AS NAME, e.last_name AS LAST_NAME, e.hired_date AS HIRED_DATE,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY e.id ASC) as ROW_NUM, COUNT(a.id) as NUM_CLOSED FROM employee e LEFT JOIN assigned_tickets a ON e.id=a.employee_id AND a.status='CLOSED' GROUP BY e.id [42001-173]`

Expecting to obtain:

```
id name surname date       row#  num of closed tkts
1 elvis presley 1967-10-10  1    1
```

If trying to fix i write:
`ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY e.id ASC)`
I obtain:

```
1 elvis presley 1967-10-10   2   0
```

Where num of closed tkts is calculated using `COUNT(a.id) ... GROUP BY e.id`

ResultSet sql mapping(just for general order):

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name="EmpDtoMapping",
    classes={
            @ConstructorResult(
                    targetClass=com.alexchulkin.dto.EmpDto.class,
                    columns={
                            @ColumnResult(name="ID", type = Long.class),
                            @ColumnResult(name="NAME", type = String.class),
                            @ColumnResult(name="LAST_NAME", type = String.class),
                            @ColumnResult(name="HIRED_DATE", type = Date.class),
                            @ColumnResult(name="ROW_NUM", type = Integer.class),
                            @ColumnResult(name="NUM_CLOSED", type = BigInteger.class)
                    })})
```

**UPD2** during the start of JBOSS both the h2 and postgres drivers are deployed:

```
20:24:52,004 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
20:24:52,022 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
20:25:05,786 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.3)
20:25:08,716 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = DI-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war_org.postgresql.Driver_9_3
```

Persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="entityManager">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <!-- Annotated entity classes -->
    <class>com.alexchulkin.domain.Emp</class>
    <class>com.alexchulkin.domain.Tkt</class>
    <class>com.alexchulkin.domain.AssignedTkt</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/di_project" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" />
        <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="/schema.sql"/>-->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: *Hibernate laments*: what does that mean, precisely? Post the code you would like to execute, the expected result of that code, and the actual result.

Comment: First of all check (https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-display-generated-sql-to-console-show_sql-format_sql-and-use_sql_comments/) what query Hibernate sends to DB, just in case.

Comment: You said you're using postgres, but the exception is a org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException, so it comes from H2, not Postgres.

Comment: @JBNizet thanx.

Comment: You may use Projection properties to get the row count and other properties for example : projections.add(Projections.rowCount()); and add it to your criteria